# jQuery - How to return a value from jQuery function (not an ajax call)

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have following `jQuery` function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
        alert(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
    });
});
```

I want to return these two values (`e.pageX` and `e.pageY`) in another function. How can I do this?

I tried with this

```
function getMousePosition(e)
{
    var tt = jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
            return (e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
        });
    });
    alert(tt);
}
```

`getMousePosition(e)` will be called from another function.

Can anybody help in this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Below is a scenario:
1. I click on an element on web page.
2. It opens a popup menu and opens a jQuery Dialog Box.
2. There is an image/icon in opened jQuery Dialog box, now when I click on that Icon, furthermore it opens a popup menu. Now when I click on an Icon in jQuery Dialog then it return Negative value for first time. Second time it return positive value.

Comment: For event-driven code like this you'd normally put your code in the event handler, or call a function from the event handler. What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: I want to use these values to assign to it's calling function's variable and then want to use it do display one popup based on Mouse's position.

Comment: The jQuery wiki has an example automatically updating : http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position, If you're moving the data thats a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your handler and giving it a variable to store the results. Then you can manipulate the variable however you like

```
var position = {},    //    store position here
    mouseMoveHandler = function(e){
        position.pageX = e.pageX;
        position.pageY = e.pageY;

        myFunction(); // you have to call your function after the position results are populated
    };

//  your function that handles the results
var myFunction = function(){
    alert(position.pageX+', '+position.pageY);
};

// give your handler to mousemove
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#target").mousemove(mouseMoveHandler);
});

// every time mousemove is triggered, the results will be in 'position' variable
```

an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/eXVKg/

Comment: When I use `alert(position.pageX);` after `jQuery` function call, I am getting `undefined` as an alert value.

Comment: Don't forget that everything is async here. Maybe you 'alert' the vaiable before it's populated. I'll give you an example with alert.

Comment: Yes. Please... dying for it :)

Comment: In the `mouseMoveHandler` I am getting value but outside, not!

Comment: +1 from me for all your effort. But now I m having an issue that my popup menu is also moving around with mouse pointer and I am not able to select an option from that popup menu :( . My aim was to assign mouse pointer's value to my popup menu so that it can be displayed at mouse's position.

Comment: I wanted to grab that mouse position only when Mouse is clicked. Because on mousemove it's impossible for me to select any option.

Comment: Then get the mouse position on click, not on mousemove.

Comment: Yes. Did it and working. But only problem is that when I first time click it then it gives me Negative but on second click it return correct value and popup is displayed.

Comment: make a jsfiddle example so we can see your problem

Comment: Actually I don't have jsfiddle account. I am editing my question further more details so will definitely get idea.

Comment: Edited my question. Please have a look on it.

Comment: One another solution you can suggest that when I click it first time, Can I wait for response (for positive value) and then I can call my function which opens popupmenu?

Comment: Take a look here -> http://jsfiddle.net/eXVKg/1/ Open your debugging console, and click on the 'Move here' word. You console will get you to my breakpoint. There, inspect the e variable. It has a pageX and pageY value, and they are the correct ones. ( feel free to edit my jsfiddle and just click on update to get a new link and show it to us )

Comment: Ok. Doing it and check it

Comment: In myFunction(e, which, optval) I am opening popup menu.In my case position.pageX and position.pageY is not getting myfunction(). And when I alert it in my proj, first e.pageX and e.pageY giving Negative value. Can you see my updated code? Read my comment there above myFunction()

Comment: Better make a working example so I can see the problem. Else we are wasting our time with comments.

Comment: You're right. But my function is divided in junks (so many other function and combination of php code). So it's hard to put it all together. But let me just edit your link with updated code of mine with sample code.

Answer (score -2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
        MouseCallback(e);        
    });
});

function MouseCallback(e) {
    alert(e.pageX+", "+y:e.pageY);
    // Do other things.
}
```